# Problemas con grid-layout

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando el comienzo del diseño de una pagina usando grid-layout. Y me enfrento a dos problemas. El primero es que no se como hacer que el footer este pegado al final de la pagina. Tan solo lo logro cuando el div que se encarga del contenido este repleto de información. Si esta vacio (como en el ejemplo que adjunto abajo) el pie se me queda a media pagina.

Ademas tengo un pequeño problema que he decidido meterlo junto a esta pregunta, que es que en la cabecera, el contenido de dentro que sera una futura barra de navegación aparece entre medias.

[image: SITUACION]

```css
.header, .footer, .main {
  padding: 1.2em;
}

.header {
   background-color: blue; /*#f5f5f5*/
}
.footer {
   background-color: red; /*#f5f5f5*/
  }
.main {
   background-color: #BBDEFB;
  }

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  /* Grid de 3x5 */
  /* 3 columnas: 1a de 200px, 2a como margen (1%), 3a ocupa el espacio restante */
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1% 1fr;
  /* 5 filas: grid-rows: 1a, 3a y 5a ancho automático, 2a y 4a como margen de 15px */
  grid-template-rows: auto 15px auto 15px auto;
}

.header,
.footer {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.header {
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 10%;
}

.footer {
  grid-row: 5;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.main {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row: 3;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <p>cabecera</p>
    </header>
    <div class="main">
      <p>contenido</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>pie</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: No te preocupes por el footer, ya que cuando lo llenes de contenido el footer se ajustara

Comment: si claro eso hace ahora, el tema es que ahora mismo que la pagina no tiene contenido mas que la palabra contenido. La caja del pie esta a media pantalla